# What's the difference between different quality pets?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was reading [this first-hand account](http://wow.joystiq.com/2012/08/03/my-first-day-with-mists-of-pandarias-pet-battles/) of Pet Battles in Mists of Pandaria and found an interesting question the author wasn't sure about.

> On the way back to Audrey, I caught a Black Lamb, a Squirrel, and finally the loathsome Stormwind Rat. **The Squirrel is a rare-quality pet and the Stormwind Rat is a poor-quality pet, but I wasn't entirely sure what that meant.**

What is the difference between different quality pets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the official [Mists of Pandaria site](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/game/mists-of-pandaria/feature/pet-battle) they state:

> Quality designates the overall strength of your pet's stats and will vary on every pet that you catch.

And in one of the [blue posts](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6079670229) this was elaborated on:

> Pets that are captured in the world have varying levels of quality, just like an item would.  The quality stat is randomly determined every time a pet spawns.  Higher quality pets get a larger stat allotment each time you level.  Be on the lookout for Rares!